# Problem with submit logo of app on App Store

Tags: ios

I have a problem when I try to submit my logo on apple store connect for the app , they say I need to do the size of 1024*1024 pixels. I made this thing in illustrator but when I try again it shows me the same error , what can I do?
[1st](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzrIc.png)
[2nd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAZNq.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there may be some problem with the resolution of the image. User Preview in mac to set the size 1024 * 1024 and keep the resolution as pixels/cm. After changing size try to upload the image to apple store connect.

Hope this help you.